# How do I read from standard input again after an EOF?

Tags: c, haskell, stdin, eof, io-monad

I have the following C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void readAndEchoAll(void) {
    for(;;) {
        char buf[100];
        ssize_t size = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if(size <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        fwrite(buf, 1, size, stdout);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    puts("Reading and echoing STDIN until first EOF...");
    readAndEchoAll();
    puts("Got first EOF. Now reading and echoing STDIN until second EOF...");
    readAndEchoAll();
    puts("Got second EOF.");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it works the way I want it to. Here's what it does:

```
Reading and echoing STDIN until first EOF...
asdf
^Dasdf
Got first EOF. Now reading and echoing STDIN until second EOF...
fdsa
^Dfdsa
Got second EOF.
```

I'm trying to create an equivalent Haskell program. Here's my attempt:

```hs
readAndEchoAll :: IO ()
readAndEchoAll = do
    buf <- getContents
    putStr buf

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Reading and echoing STDIN until first EOF..."
    readAndEchoAll
    putStrLn "Got first EOF. Now reading and echoing STDIN until second EOF..."
    -- ???
    readAndEchoAll
    putStrLn "Got second EOF."
```

This doesn't work. Here's what it does:

```
Reading and echoing STDIN until first EOF...
asdf
^Dasdf
Got first EOF. Now reading and echoing STDIN until second EOF...
readtwice.hs: <stdin>: hGetContents: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

How do I make this work like the C program? <s>I assume that I need to put some equivalent of `clearerr(stdin);` where I have `-- ???`, but I'm not sure what that equivalent is.</s>

**Update:** Turns out `clearerr` is a bit of a red herring, as it's exclusive to the standard C API. When using the POSIX API, you can just read again without needing to do anything equivalent to it. So rather than make Haskell do anything extra, I need to make it not do something: not prevent further reads once it sees EOF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `getContents`, because `hGetContents` (semi-)closes the handle it's passed and `getContents` calls `hGetContents`. But there's no problem with reading from a handle again after EOF with most of the other functions from the standard library. Here's a simple but inefficient example of reading all the characters without using `getContents`:

```hs
import Control.Exception
import System.IO.Error

readAll = go [] where
    handler cs err = if isEOFError err
        then return (reverse cs)
        else throwIO err
    go cs = catch (do
        c <- getChar
        go (c:cs))
        (handler cs)

main = do
    all <- readAll
    putStrLn $ "got: " ++ all
    putStrLn "go again, mate"
    all <- readAll
    putStrLn $ "got: " ++ all
```

If you want better efficiency, there are various functions available for reading lines-at-a-time or other large chunks in the standard library, rather than one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of the GHC source code shows that `clearerr()` is not used at all there.  However, you can open `/dev/stdin` again, since it looks like you're using Linux or similar.  Try this:

```hs
stdin2 <- openFile "/dev/stdin" ReadMode
```

You can also use `hDuplicate`.  See here: [Portably opening a handle to stdin many times in a single session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123897/portably-opening-a-handle-to-stdin-many-times-in-a-single-session)

Comment: This seems to imply that Haskell immediately closes a handle once it reads an EOF from it. Can you confirm this is what you're saying? (See also the update to my question.)

Comment: EOF does not close the file handle. What's more, this way of doing things is very unsafe, because of the way lazy IO interleaves effects.

Comment: @DanielWagner did you mean the `openFile`, or the `hDuplicate` way? or both?

Comment: @WillNess Calling `hGetContents` on two copies of `stdin` is unsafe, whether you got those two copies from `openFile` or `hDuplicate`. It's not "unsafe" in the "type unsafe" sense, but it's "unsafe" in the sense that the uncontrollable order in which lazy evaluation forces computations will control which of the two results of `getContents` "see" which inputs.

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks. so a char on stdin might enter either one of the two handles, nondeterministically? and if I, say, stop using `h1` at some point in my `do` block and only refer to `h2` from that point on, the result will be that some chars on stdin might get skipped when I "look" at it only through `h2`, is that it? if I use only `hGetChar`, say? or is the problem lies only and specifically in `hGetContents`? what about `hGetBuf`?

Comment: @WillNess The problem is specifically with `hGetContents`: the order of evaluation of pure values that depend on the `String` returned by `hGetContents` determines which of the two `String`s contains the next inputted character. With `hGetBuf` and friends, the order of execution of `IO` actions determines it; but this is okay, because we have a solid story for controlling what order `IO` actions are executed in (that's the whole point of `IO` in the first place).

Comment: @DanielWagner aha. great. thanks! one more thing: so hGetBuf, say, is atomic? i.e. not lazy I mean? yeah looks like it must be, it returns an Int count of chars read.  thanks!

Comment: @WillNess As you say it depends what you mean by atomic. I would be wary of calling it on the same handle from two different threads (read: I would source-dive first); but then I can't think of a time when I have wanted to do something like that anyway. But if what you really mean is "Does it do lazy IO/call `unsafeInterleaveIO` like `hGetContents` does?" then the answer is no.

Comment: "So once a file reaches EOF, it's at EOF forever." That seems to be false, given @DanielWagner's answer

Comment: @JosephSible: Fair enough, I removed that sentence.